# How can we find tables which do not have any indexes (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL.

How can we find tables which do not have any indexes?
Can you show me a sql statement to find that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view `pg_tables` has a convenient `hasindexes` column:

```
select * from pg_tables where not hasindexes
```

Comment: Oh.. very convenient!! Thank you!